# How to handle resultDictionary nulls in swift?

Tags: swift, resultset, fmdb

With FMDB resultset's resultDictionary method returns a dictionary for each row where the keys are the column names which have a value or are NSNulls. So I am trying to figure out how best to handle these and where.

So with the new update of swift I need to change my code and in the process I am looking at some refactoring.

So as it stands the following line of code's "as" needs to be made to "as?" or "as!" :

```
resultsArray.append(resultSet.resultDictionary() as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
```

Robert stated I should handle them like [this](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/343#issuecomment-98980067). But it got me thinking about a better solution and thus I am looking for some advice on how I should refactor:

1. I could get the optional, find nulls and replace the NSNulls with
       empty string literals "" and this handle empty strings somewhere
       else in my app.
2. I could just leave them as is and force unwrap.

`public class func queryGetAllRowsFromTableAsArrayOfHashes() -> Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>?` {

```
var resultsArray = Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>()
let database = DBUtility.getDatabaseHandle()

//Perform query and place result into a dictionary.
self.log().info("Getting all rows from: \(self.getTableName())")
if let resultSet = database.executeQuery(self.getAllRowsStatement()) {
    self.log().info("Query run")
    while resultSet.next() {
        //adds a dictionary of the result row to the array.
        resultsArray.append(resultSet.resultDictionary() as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
    }
    self.log().info("Results array: \(resultsArray)")
    return resultsArray;
}else{
   self.log().error("DB Error: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
}
return nil;
}
```

Anyone got some advice on where this should be tackled?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a check in if statement like this

```
if var dict = resultSet.resultDictionary() as Dictionary<String,AnyObject> 
{
  resultsArray.append(resultSet.resultDictionary() as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
}
```

It will only append the value in array if there is non null value.
hope it will help you.If value is null then if statement will not be executed.

Comment: But it is not the dictionary that is null.. just some of the contents.. eg "address" -> NSNull

Comment: In these case you need to do the same when you access elements in the dict like  "address"

Comment: when ever you fetch the value from the resultsArray you need to put the same check for all the fields which might be nil.